# MDT 2012 Image Capture

Tags: windows-server-2012, mdt-2012

I am using `MDT 2012 Update 1`.  Attempting to Deploy 2012 DC to a VM, run windows updates, and then sysprep/capture that image.  This is the same task sequence process I have used for Windows 7 / 2008 R2 and it works fine.

However, for 2012 DC it deploys the image, starts running/installing updates and then runs sysprep and on reboot it goes to a `"Choose an option"` screen if I choose `"Exit and continue to Windows Server 2012"` it reboots and goes back to same screen.
Any ideas?

[image: Choose an option screen]

Comment: This screen is the WinRE for OS recovery, I'm just not understanding when/how its getting applied and why the OS that was functional beforehand stops functioning.

Comment: How are you running the "capture"?

Comment: I am running MDT's default capture task sequence.  My entire task sequence can be seen here if needed: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46718/www/files/ts.xml

Comment: If I understand correctly you are using one task sequence to deploy, updates and then sysprep and capture?

Comment: That is correct.  Same sequence I have been using for 2008 R2 and Windows 7 to create images for deployment.

Comment: Woah, never knew you could do that. I would try splitting the task sequence to two task sequences. One to deploy / update and then put an additional one to capture. I have always kicked off the capture by running the lite-touch script manually and using a sysprep and capture task sequence.

Comment: Did you install the [WADK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652) on your system with MDT? Or are you using WAIK?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to use the same unattended.xml answer file for both Win7 and ServerOS. You would need to use WISM to build a new answer file specific for that OS. I would highly recomend using a different task sequence for the server builds and deploys. Futhermore, are you building this image in VM? If not, you're wasting time. Always, Always, Always, build your images in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem yesterday with Windows 8.

It seems as though the problem might be related to a patch that gets installed that doesn't make the Windows Update client do a reboot after installation.

To solve (or rather work around) the problem, I opened the Task Sequence and in the "Custom Tasks" folder after the second Windows Update task, I added a "Restart computer" task.

You may want to give this a try.